# Show/Hide Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on my website, and decided to use Javascript to help me show/hide certain elements. The only problem is, I'm new to Javascript. I've worked on this for a while now, but I can't seem to find out what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function ShowHide(divId){
                var $home = 'homecontent',
                $art = 'artworkcontent',
                $poe = 'poetrycontent',
                $pro = 'programmingcontent';

                if {divId == $home}{
                    document.getElementById($art).style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById($poe).style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById($pro).style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById($home).style.display='block';
                }
                else if {divId == $art}{
                    document.getElementById($home).style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById($poe).style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById($pro).style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById($art).style.display='block';
                }
                else if {divId == $poe}{
                    document.getElementById($art).style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById($home).style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById($pro).style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById($poe).style.display='block';
                }
                else if {divId == $pro}{
                    document.getElementById($art).style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById($poe).style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById($home).style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById($pro).style.display='block';
                }
            }
```

Comment: What's with the curly braces in your conditional statements??? Always remember to check your console :)

Comment: Is that valid syntax for the IF conditions? (curly braces instead of parentheses?)

Comment: last else if statement can probably resort to just else too..

Comment: Make sure you are constantly debugging! Check out `Firebug` for `Firefox`, or in `Chrome`, press `F12`, and check the `console`!

Comment: Should divId be stored into a private variable, before being compared to other private variables?  just a general quesiton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition for an `if` statement should be inside of parentheses, not braces:

```
if (divId == $home){ 
   ^              ^
```